# Codeigniter sessions issue in IE9

Tags: codeigniter

Session expiring in IE9 when I have upload any images using ajax call in codeigniter, and I have tried this
1.Writing MY_Session.php file in application/libraries/  but show this error CI_Session not found

```
      <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  
    require_once BASEPATH . '/libraries/Session.php';  
    class MY_Session extends CI_Session{  
       function __construct()  
        {  
            parent::__construct();  
            $this->CI->session = $this;  
        }  
        function sess_update()  
        {  
            // Do NOT update an existing session on AJAX calls.  
            if (!$this->CI->input->is_ajax_request())  
                return parent::sess_update();  
        }  
    }  ?>
    /* End of file MY_Session.php */  
    /* Location: ./application/libraries/MY_Session.php */

config.php :
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: session should have anything to do with type of browser.

Comment: I didn't get you, could you explain in brief

Comment: Session is really configured and managed at the server. Browser may not have any role in it. Please provide code to get more help

Comment: I have searched solution in stack, many people provide solution as need to write MY_session.php in libraries folder.

Comment: what is your session setting in config.php. Please add that in your question

Comment: see this link https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/205718/#958488

Comment: thanks alot Girish.No need to add any code. Simply I changed the 
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE; TO
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
this enough

Answer (score 1):

You have to first load CI instance then you are able to load any library

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session{ 

     function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =&get_instance();

        $this->ci->load->library('session');

    }

}
```